# add event onClick to the last element of a dropdown

Tags: angularjs, dropdownbox

Let's say I have a dropdown list and I want to add an onClick event to the last element of the list, as e.g:

- London
- Paris
- Milan
- Add New City +

**ng-change** directive just helps me if I have more than one element in the dropdown, otherwise if I have a list like this (with only one element):

- Add New City +

I will never be able to set the onClick event to the only item, since it never changes the value of the combo box.

**UPDATE**

```
<select ng-model="customer.selectedCity"  ng-options="opt as opt.name for opt in customer.cityOptions"
  ng-init="model="customer.selectedCity"   = customer.cityOptions[0]"
  ng-change="onCustomerCitySelected(customer)" ></select>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this without using `ng-change` at all. Consider the following:

**HTML template**

```
<select ng-model="selectedIndex"
        ng-options="index as name for (index, name) in menu"> 
</select>
```

**JavaScript**

```
app.controller('SelectCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.menu = ['London','Paris','Milan','Add new city+'];

  $scope.$watch('selectedIndex', function(val) {
    $scope.selectedCity = $scope.menu[val];      

    if (val == $scope.menu.length - 1) {
      $scope.addNewCity();
      $scope.selectedIndex = $scope.selectedCity = null;
    }
  });

  $scope.addNewCity = function() {
    alert('Add city from select');
  };
});
```

You could also think about using `ui-bootstrap` dropdown.

**HTML template**

```
<div class="btn-group" dropdown>
  <button type="button" 
          class="btn btn-primary">{{ vm.selectedCity || 'Not selected' }}
  </button>
  <button type="button" 
          class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" 
          dropdown-toggle>
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li ng-repeat="item in vm.menu">
      <a ng-if="!$last" href="#" 
         ng-bind="item"
         ng-click="vm.selectedCity = item"></a> 
      <a ng-if="$last" href="#" 
         ng-bind="item"
         ng-click="vm.addNewCity()"></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
app.controller('DropdownCtrl', function() {
  var vm = this;
  vm.menu = ['London','Paris','Milan','Add new city+'];

  vm.addNewCity = function() {
    alert('Add city from dropdown');
    vm.selectedCity = null; 
  };
});
```

Examples above would result in something like this

[image]

Related plunker with all teh codes here http://plnkr.co/edit/szA1pt

Comment: thanks for your time, this helped me to achieve what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to add default value just like this:

```
<select ng-model="model2" ng-options="item for item in items2" ng-change="processItemChange(model2)">
      <option value="">Select Value From Items2</option>
</select>
```

So now you can add your `ng-change` function to define whether new value is `add new value`

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/S4r1dhKFMutllESklLFA?p=preview

Comment: Hi @ababashka, thank you very much for your comment. I gave you +1

I thought about something similar, that would solve my problem, but I cannot have those default values in my list, and hiding them is not an option, since it would only work the first time you change the value of the combo.

Comment: @unpix: what exactly do you want to see in the very end? Can you please provide some start code from which i could give some advice? Thanks.

Comment: Basically I want to have an onclick event to the last item of the list, exactly as in the example. I updated the code with what I have in my view,
I need to change the ng-change directive somehow to get what I want to achieve. Otherwise, if I have the list with only 1 element, the value of "Add new City +" 
won't change.

Thanks once again